# Duplicate namespaces in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm converting a Visual Studio Web Site Project to a Web Application Project. My problem is the controls defined in the apx pages are creating errors when referenced from the aspx.cs pages.

[image: Image show Visual Studio error message on mouse hover]

As the picture shows (I've removed a portion of the full namespace for privacy), the namespace is found twice, or something? and one is available and the other is not? I have no idea what "use the navigation bar to switch context" means, I cant find the "navigation bar" it's talking about.

Further reading on the [two project types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx)

Comment: For reference your `Navigation bar` is the `File | Edit | View | ...` bar a the top of VS.

Comment: @JayGould thanks, but I still don't know what button or action or option it is referring too

Comment: @Nnoel I'm having the same problem. Did you find a solution?
At the top of my window I have three dropdowns. From the left it litsts namespaces, classes and methods.

I have to namespaces that look Identical in the first list.

Comment: this was a while ago, but as I recall you cant have over-lapping namespaces, like if you got "myProject.mySolution" as a solution AND "myProject.myLib.mySolution", Visual Studio had issues with that.